# Concise and robust way to read a line of space-separated integers in Go

Tags: arrays, parsing, go

I have been giving HackerRank a try where the problems often require reading lines of integers into arrays (slices).

For many of the problems, my parsing code ends up being larger than the algorithmic meat of the solution. For instance, that was the case in [Sherlock and Array](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-array)

Any ideas on how to concisely parse a space-separated line of integers into a slice? `fmt.Scanf` doesn't support slices and when using `bufio` I get long solutions.

Some requirements:

- You can only use the standard library.
- The solution should be concise, the shorter the better.
- Error checks shouldn't be skipped. I know that the input is well defined in HackerRank and you should be able to cut corners, but please don't, it's bad practice.
- It should be reasonably efficient.

**NOTE:**
The parser should only consume a single line and not the full input.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I have done some hackerrank problems too, and here is what I came up with. Typically, problems start with the number of items in the array:

```
func main() {
    var N int
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &N)
    line := make([]int, N)
    for i, _ := range line {
        fmt.Scanf("%d", &line[i])
    }

    // Do something with the values
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// inputs space separated list of integers, outputs []int64
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(parse("100 200 300"))
}

func parse(i string) (o []int64) {
    // from https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#example_Scanner_custom
    s := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(i))
    splitter := func(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {
        advance, token, err = bufio.ScanWords(data, atEOF)
        if err == nil && token != nil {
            x, err := strconv.ParseInt(string(token), 10, 32)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            o = append(o, x)
        }
        return
    }
    s.Split(splitter)
    for s.Scan() {
    }
    return o
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call this concise, in fact it looks similar to what I wrote.

Comment: ./shrug if you want tiny functions try ruby :)

Comment: Or Python, or Haskell :) I would like to use go, but it sucks to spend more time on the parsing part than on the meat of problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`fmt.Scanf`](https://godoc.org/fmt#Scanf), but you need to keep track of the values you're getting.

```
// a.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

func main() {
    var (
        next int
        nums []int
    )

    for {
        n, err := fmt.Scanf("%d", &next)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        if n == 0 {
            break
        }

        nums = append(nums, next)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", nums)
}
```

---

```
$ echo "4 8 15 16 23 42" | go run a.go
[]int{4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42}
```

Comment: This is the best option so far. You don't need to check for n since you will always get an error if n != 1

Comment: Actually, I stay corrected, this doesn't work because it doesn't tell apart EOLs and EOFs, it should only consume a line.

Comment: You wanted to _parse a space-separated **line** of integers into a slice_.

Comment: Exactly, `echo -e '1 2 3 4\n5 6 7 8' | go run a.go` puts everything in the same array instead of a single line, which is what I was asking for.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for giving it a try!! :)

Comment: `fmt.Scan("%s", &input)` or `fmt.Scanln("%s", &input)` doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

1) read string

2) prepend `[` and append `]`

3) parse as json into []int?

```
var input = "1,2,3"
var answer []int
j := []byte(fmt.Sprintf("[%s]",input))
err:= json.Unmarshal(j, &input)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
for k,v := range input {
   fmt.Printf("Element №%v is %v\n", k,v)
}
```

also using split strings (https://godoc.org/strings#Split)
and https://godoc.org/strconv#ParseInt

```
input:= "1,2,3"
temp := strings.Split(input, ",")
var answer []int

for _,v := range temp {
  i,err := strconv.ParseInt(v)
  if err != nill {
     panic(err)
  }
  answer = append(answer, i)
}
```

UPD: just found that the numbers are SPACE separated.
So, this code have to do the thing:

```
input:= "1 2 3"
temp := strings.Split(input, " ")
var answer []int

for _,v := range temp {
  i,err := strconv.ParseInt(v)
  if err != nill {
     panic(err)
  }
  answer = append(answer, i)
}
```

Comment: Nice _abuse_ of json :) However, strings are space-separated (not comma-separated) and reading the full line is pretty inefficient in space.

Answer (score 1):

```
func main() {
    arr := make([]int, 0)

    reader := bufio.NewReaderSize(os.Stdin, 1024*1024)

    for {
        line, _, err := reader.ReadLine()
        if err != nil {
          if err == io.EOF {
            break
          }
          panic(err)
        }


        str := strings.Split(string(line), " ")

        for i:=0; i<len(str); i++ {
            v, _ := strconv.Atoi(str[i])
            arr = append(arr, v)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(arr)
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

I've used this for those times playing in *hackerrank* (so concise, but not tested for *humans*):

```
func scanInt(n int) []int {
    input := make([]int, n)
    buffer := make([]interface{}, n)

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        buffer[i] = &input[i]
    }

    fmt.Scanln(buffer...)

    return input
}
```