# How to take input with whitespace distance in golang

Tags: go, input, whitespace

I wanted to take some input from user based on white space in golang.
The current code is...

```
fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &N)
var a [10]int
for n := 0; n < N; n++ {
    fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &a[n])
}
```

This code will let me take input in terminal like...

```
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

So, a[] = {1,2,3,4,5}
But I would like to take input in terminal like...

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

So, a[] = {1,2,3,4,5}
So please help to find what should I change in the for-loop above.

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498430/concise-and-robust-way-to-read-a-line-of-space-separated-integers-in-go/37499149

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. This will read in the first number which is the size of the array you want to create, then the next line will be the items of length (n) in the array

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
  reader := bufio.NewReaderSize(os.Stdin, 1024 * 1024)

  nTemp, err := strconv.ParseInt(readLine(reader), 10, 64)
  checkError(err)
  n := int32(nTemp)

  arrTemp := strings.Split(readLine(reader), " ")

  var arr []int32

  for i := 0; i < int(n); i++ {
      arrItemTemp, err := strconv.ParseInt(arrTemp[i], 10, 64)
      checkError(err)
      arrItem := int32(arrItemTemp)
      arr = append(arr, arrItem)
  }

  fmt.Printf("%#v, arr", arr)
}
```

So when I try with your given input e.g:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5

// I get the following:
[]int32{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, arr
```

The question you have asked seems to be common in sites like [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/dashboard) in any of the featured questions.

Comment: @harshdadhaniya feel free to upvote and mark the answer as accepted. This will help future comers know the answer is of use.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you martinomburajr & Casey Flynn.

I went through your answers and I did my own trial-and-error.
And finally found the somultion.

```
var N int
fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &N)
a := make([]int, N)
for n := range a {
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &a[n])
}
fmt.Scanf("\n")
```

And it is working fine for my requirement.
Thank you so much for the help.